# Desbordamiento de cadenas en C

Tags: c

¿Existe?

Es una duda de alguien que esta comenzando a programar, pero por ejemplo, si yo declaro esto:

`char cadena[11];`

Por que me deja asignarle una cadena que tenga 30 elementos ? no debería haber un desbordamiento de memoria y que me mostrase cosas raras al sacar la cadena con un printf ?

Por poner un ejemplo:

```
void solicitarCadena(){
    char cadena[11];

    printf("\nIntroduce una cadena de 10 elementos como maximo:\n");

    gets(cadena);

    printf("%s",cadena);
}
```

En ese ejemplo aunque introduzca una cadena de 50 elementos me la muestra de manera integra sin dar ningún tipo de problema.

Es el compilador que estoy usando (dev c/c++) haciendo magia por debajo para que funcione?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: algun experto te va a contestar mejor, pero no. Funciona de milagro, y en realidad estas pisando memoria que no corresponde a esa cadena. C usa punteros, con lo cual, no controla los tamaños de las cosas. en ese programa no pasa nada. pero en uno real, capaz que pisaste el valor de otra variable, otra cadena u otra cosa. El lunes seguro alguien va a poder contestarme mejor.

Comment: Entonces gbianchi incluso aunque haga un validador con un do while que controle que en dicha cadena no llegue al printf si tiene mas de 10 elementos no serviria de nada porque ya esta pisando otras variables en el propio gets ?

Como puedo hacer para limitar el damaño de dicha cadena en el propio gets para no pisar otras variables ?

Comment: no recuerdo tanto, aguarda a que algun experto pueda orientarte mas que yo. Pero si, pisaste otras variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considera la siguiente modificación:

```
int main(void)
 {
char cadena[11];
char cadena2[11];
printf("\nIntroduce una cadena de 10 elementos como maximo:\n");
gets(cadena);
printf("%s\n",cadena);
printf("%s\n", cadena2);
return 0;
 }
```

Se obtiene:

> Introduce una cadena de 10 elementos como maximo:
>   una cadena mas larga de lo debido
>   arga de lo debido

Efectivamente desbordando el buffer y escribiendo en otros espacios de memoria.

En la siguiente url de documentación advierten sobre esto:
http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/gets

> Notes
>   The gets() function does not perform bounds checking, therefore this function is extremely vulnerable to buffer-overflow attacks.

Comment: Muchas gracias, el enlace que me has facilitado me ha resultado muy útil.

Que debería hacer para evitar dicho desbordamiento con las cadenas en c si quiero que me introduzcan una cadena por teclado y no quiero utilizar archivos ?

Comment: Podrias utilizar `scanf("%10c",cadena);` especificando asi el largo maximo de la cadena

Comment: @Oscar Puedes tambien usar `fgets(cadena, 10, stdin)` que tiene sobre `scanf()` la ventaja de leer cadenas que contengan espacios.

Comment: %c en scanf también lee espacios

Comment: @Klaimmore Cierto, había leído errónamente `%s`. De cualquier forma, `fgets()` es lo más parecido a `gets()` que tenemos, y que controla el número de caracteres leídos.